# EmberJS displaying a formatted date

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to display a formatted date in EmberJS, but it's outputting a blank string.

```
{{#each}}
  {{formatedDrawDate}}
{{/each}}
```

Output

```
<script id="metamorph-9-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-9-end type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

CoffeeScript

```
App.GroupsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  formatedDrawDate: (->
    moment(@get 'drawDate').format 'MMM Do YY'
  ).property('drawDate')
```

The data:

```
App.GROUPS = [
  {
    id: 1
    drawDate: new Date()
  },
  # ...
]
```

My Route:

```
App.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.GROUPS
```

I can see a cleanly formatted date in the console under the controller. I'm not sure why it's not displaying, though.

Comment: are you returning something from your property ?. Add a 'return' before 'moment(@get.....': return moment(@get 'drawDate').format 'MMM Do YY'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `itemController` and put your `formattedDrawDate`property on it. Your code as it is now simply adds a single property to your controller - not to each of it's `content`.

```
App.GroupsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'group'

App.GroupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  formatedDrawDate: (->
    moment(@get 'drawDate').format 'MMM Do YY'
  ).property('drawDate')
```

[The documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html) has a bit more info.